# The meaning and usage of hyphenated suffix -с

Tags: словоупотребление

I was reading a short story from Chekhov called "Который из трех?" when I came across a hyphenated suffix **-с** attached to certain words. Here are a few examples:

> И при такой самой природе как приятно, знаете **ли-с**, любить такую
>   приятную особу, как вы... Но я несчастлив!
>
> Очень **несчастлив-с**!
>
> Ни... **ничего-с**! Я хотел, собственно говоря, вас побеспокоить...

I couldn't find what it means. I even looked through my reference grammar book, but to no avail. I reckon it's either an archaic grammar (the story was published in 1882) or some very obscure one. I would like to know what it means, when is it used and to what sort of words can it be attached?

Answer (score 12):

Shortened from **сударь** over the course of centuries, it's basically used to add a respectful tone to the conversation. It went entirely out of use after the revolution, and its meaning has to be learned by present-day Russians — by default, it just registers as "something people always say in 19th-century books for some reason".

Comment: Interesting and helpful comment. Incidentally, сударь is in Wiktionary, and there is even an entry for -с (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D1%81#Russian)

Answer (score 6):

Это **словое́рс** (тж. словое́р, словое́рик) — название частицы -с (написание по старой орфографии — -съ), прибавляемой в русском языке к концу слов в определённых ситуациях: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81

Answer (score 5):

Just a side note. In "Eugene Onegin" Onegin's neighbours think him as being very impolite person for (besides other things) his constantly omitting suffix "-s":

> "Сосед наш неуч, сумасбродит,
>   Он фармазон; он пьет одно
>   Стаканом красное вино;
>   Он дамам к ручке не подходит;
>   Все **да** да **нет**; не скажет **да-с**
>   Иль **нет-с**". Таков был общий глас.
>
> А.С. Пушкин "Евгений Онегин", II, V
>
> "Our neighbor is a boor; acts like a crackbrain;
>   he's a Freemason; he
>   drinks only red wine, by the tumbler;
>   he won't go up to kiss a lady's hand;
>   'tis all '**yes,**' '**no**' - he'll not say '**yes, sir,**'
>   or '**no, sir.**' " This was the general voice.
>
> Translated by E. Nabokov